# How to pass more than one value to a variable through EXTRA_OECMAKE from a bitbake recipe?

Tags: cmake, yocto, bitbake, openembedded

I need to pass a variable to from my bitbake (.bb) recipe to cmake. I know I can do that by EXTRA_OECMAKE. This what I have in my recipe:

```
EXTRA_OECMAKE = "-Deigen_INCLUDE_DIRS:PATH=${STAGING_INCDIR}/eigen3"
```

But I want the variable **eigen_INCLUDE_DIRS** to have more than one value.
I tried separating the values with a semicolon:

```
EXTRA_OECMAKE = "-Deigen_INCLUDE_DIRS:PATH=${STAGING_INCDIR}/eigen3;${B};${WORKDIR}/${BP}/third_party/eigen3"
```

and also and a single quote:

```
EXTRA_OECMAKE = "-Deigen_INCLUDE_DIRS:PATH='${STAGING_INCDIR}/eigen3' '${B}' '${WORKDIR}/${BP}/third_party/eigen3'"
```

But both of them do not work. How can I append more values to the variable?

Comment: If you mean a list with "more than one value" you can do it with append or prepend assignment:
`EXTRA_OECMAKE =+ "-Deigen_INCLUDE_DIRS:PATH=${STAGING_INCDIR}/eigen3"`
`EXTRA_OECMAKE =+ "-D${B}"`
`EXTRA_OECMAKE =+ "-D${WORKDIR}/${BP}/third_party/eigen3}"`

Answer (score 1):

This is not related to bitbake/OE but entirely down to how the eigen cmake module works.  I'd ask the eigen maintainers what value they're expecting.

Comment: This is not about eigen. My question is related to assigning more than one value to a cmake variable that is passed through EXTRA_OECMAKE. **eigen_INCLUDE_DIRS** happens to be one such cmake variable that I wish to pass.

Comment: I said "eigen cmake module".  Nothing to do with EXTRA_OECMAKE as that is just a way of passing cmake's -D option.